# Change stacking of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that looks kind of like this.

```
Name          2012                  2013                       2014  
         7 8 9 10 11 12   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
 A       a b c d e f g    a b c d e f g h i j k l m   a b c d e f g h i j k l m
 B       a b c d e f g    a b c d e f g h i j k l m   a b c d e f g h i j k l m
```

and so on. The 2012, 2013, 2014 represents year and below them are its respective months, while a,b,c,d,e... represents the value of the NAME i.e. A,B.. in respective months. The a,b,c,d,e... are different for each name and are displayed here for representation purpose only.

Currently, I have done the following :

```
workbook = pd.ExcelFile('XYZ.xlsx')
df = workbook.parse(sheetname='Page1-2')
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Name"], 
              var_name="Date", value_name="Value")
```

i.e I imported my XYZ.xlsx file in df. sorted df to df2 using pd.melt. The output of df2 is something like this:

```
Name Date      Value
 A   2012      a
 A   Unnamed   b
 A   Unnamed   c
 A   Unnamed   d
 A   Unnamed   e
 A   Unnamed   f
 A   Unnamed   g
 A   2013      a
 A   Unnamed   b
 A   Unnamed   c
 A   Unnamed   d
 A   Unnamed   e
```

and so on with other years and names. I want my date column to come something like this:

```
 Date
 7/2012
 8/2012
 9/2012
 10/2012
 11/2012
 12/2012
 1/2013
 2/2013
 3/2013
 4/2013
 5/2013
 6/2013
 7/2013
 8/2013
```

According to the months and years mentioned in the initial data frame. I'm not sure how to do this. Any help is highly appreciated!

print (df.to_dict()) of my sample database

```
{'Name': {0: nan, 1: 'A', 2: 'B'}, 2012: {0: '07', 1: 'a', 2: 'a'},'Unnamed: 2': {0: '08', 1: 'b', 2: 'b'}, 'Unnamed: 3': {0: '09', 1: 'c', 2: 'c'}, 'Unnamed: 4': {0: '10', 1: 'd', 2: 'd'}, 'Unnamed: 5': {0: '11', 1: 'e', 2: 'e'}, 'Unnamed: 6': {0: '12', 1: 'f', 2: 'f'}, '2013': {0: '01', 1: 'a', 2: 'a'}, 'Unnamed: 8': {0: '02', 1: 'b', 2: 'b'}, 'Unnamed: 9': {0: '03', 1: 'c', 2: 'c'}, 'Unnamed: 10': {0: '04', 1: 'd', 2: 'd'}, 'Unnamed: 11': {0: '05', 1: 'e', 2: 'e'}, 'Unnamed: 12': {0: '06', 1: 'f', 2: 'f'}, 'Unnamed: 13': {0: '07', 1: 'a', 2: 'a'}, 'Unnamed: 14': {0: '08', 1: 'b', 2: 'b'}, 'Unnamed: 15': {0: '09', 1: 'c', 2: 'c'}, 'Unnamed: 16': {0: '10', 1: 'd', 2: 'd'}, 'Unnamed: 17': {0: '11', 1: 'e', 2: 'e'}, 'Unnamed: 18': {0: '12', 1: 'f', 2: 'f'}, '2014': {0: '01', 1: 'a', 2: 'a'}, 'Unnamed: 20': {0: '02', 1: 'b', 2: 'b'}, 'Unnamed: 21': {0: '03', 1: 'c', 2: 'c'}, 'Unnamed: 22': {0: '04', 1: 'd', 2: 'd'}, 'Unnamed: 23': {0: '05', 1: 'e', 2: 'e'}, 'Unnamed: 24': {0: '06', 1: 'f', 2: 'f'}, 'Unnamed: 25': {0: '07', 1: 'a', 2: 'a'}, 'Unnamed: 26': {0: '08', 1: 'b', 2: 'b'}, 'Unnamed: 27': {0: '09', 1: 'c', 2: 'c'}, 'Unnamed: 28': {0: '10', 1: 'd', 2: 'd'}, 'Unnamed: 29': {0: '11', 1: 'e', 2: 'e'}, 'Unnamed: 30': {0: '12', 1: 'f', 2: 'f'}}
```

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: What is `Name`? `index` or `column`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#create index with column Name
df = df.set_index('Name')
#create Multiindex with columns (add instead Unammed categories) and first row
idx = pd.Series(df.columns)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx.mask(idx.str.contains('Unnamed:')).ffill(),
              df.iloc[0]], names=('Date','Month'))
#remove first row
df = df.iloc[1:]


print (df)
Date  2012                2013          ... 2014                           
Month   07 08 09 10 11 12   01 02 03 04 ...   03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
Name                                    ...                                
A        a  b  c  d  e  f    a  b  c  d ...    c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l
B        a  b  c  d  e  f    a  b  c  d ...    c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['2012', '2013', '2014'], ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
           names=['Date', 'Month'])
```

---

```
#reshape
df2 = df.unstack().reset_index(name='Value')
df2['Date'] = df2['Month'] + '/' + df2['Date']
df2 = df2.drop('Month', axis=1)
print (df2)
       Date Name Value
0   07/2012    A     a
1   07/2012    B     a
2   08/2012    A     b
3   08/2012    B     b
4   09/2012    A     c
5   09/2012    B     c
6   10/2012    A     d
7   10/2012    B     d
8   11/2012    A     e
9   11/2012    B     e
10  12/2012    A     f
11  12/2012    B     f
```

If read `df` from file is possible add parameters `header=[0,1]` for read first and second row to `MultiIndex` and first column `Name` to `index`. Then solution is a bit changed:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', header=[0,1], index_col=[0])


idx = pd.Series(df.columns.get_level_values(0))

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx.mask(idx.str.contains('Unnamed:')).ffill(),
                                       df.columns.get_level_values(1)], 
                                       names=('Date','Month'))
print (df)
Date  2012                2013          ... 2014                           
Month   07 08 09 10 11 12   01 02 03 04 ...   03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
Name                                    ...                                
A        a  b  c  d  e  f    a  b  c  d ...    c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l
B        a  b  c  d  e  f    a  b  c  d ...    c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['2012', '2013', '2014'], ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
           names=['Date', 'Month'])
```

---

```
#reshape
df2 = df.unstack().reset_index(name='Value').rename(columns={'level_2':'Name'})
df2['Date'] = df2['Month'].astype(str) + '/' + df2['Date'].astype(str)
#df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'].radd('1/'), format='%d/%m/%y')
df2 = df2.drop('Month', axis=1)
print (df2)

       Date Name Value
0   07/2012    A     a
1   07/2012    B     a
2   08/2012    A     b
3   08/2012    B     b
4   09/2012    A     c
5   09/2012    B     c
6   10/2012    A     d
7   10/2012    B     d
8   11/2012    A     e
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but while i try to run the above command it prints out the following errer: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.

Comment: Is possible add to question `print (df.to_dict())` ? thank you.

Comment: Or maybe `print (df.head().to_dict())` for first 5 rows - because it seems my dataframe used in answer is different as you.

Comment: BTW my dataset is exactly like one i mentioned in my question. No extra column names and nothing.

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

Comment: I think need `df2['Date'] = df2['Month'].astype(str) + '/' + df2['Date'].astype(str) `

Comment: And if need convert to datetimes `df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Month'].astype(str) + '/' + df2['Date'].astype(str))`

Comment: There was again error like _ unknown string format_ but i used `errors='coerce'` in df2['Date']. Now program compiled but in the date column all value were NaT.

Comment: What about `df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'].astype(str) + '-' + df2['Month'].astype(str) + '-01')` ? No some trailing whitesapces?

Comment: Hmmm, problem is with test data or with real?

Comment: I test your data and all working nice. I add output of `df` with `df.columns`, do you get same?